# Arduino an array does not name a type

Tags: c++, arrays, types, arduino, arduino-uno

The problem is with the array. The line which declares the array has no problem, it's the ones that follow it. It seems I can't code as in C. 
How can I fix it as I need it in this format for clarity. I don't want to write a long line as there are 15 variables in this array.

Here is the code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver();

#define SERVOMIN  150 // this is the 'minimum' pulse length count (out of 4096)
#define SERVOMAX  600 // this is the 'maximum' pulse length count (out of 4096)

///// void setup /////
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pwm.begin();
  pwm.setPWMFreq(60);  // Analog servos run at ~60 Hz updates
  delay(10);
}



///// Coordonnees /////
int angles[5][3];    //angles de chaque moteur pour chaque cube
angles[0][0]=60;
angles[0][1]=120;
angles[0][2]=100;
```

Basically it's the `angles[0][0]=;` and the lines similar to it that cause the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a handful of things are allowed in global scope, and assignment is not one of them.

You are allowed to declare or define variables (and initialize them), so this is why you can define your array. One way of achieving your goal would be to initialize the array, instead of assign values to it:

```
int angles[5][3] {
                  {1, 2, 3},
                  {3, 4, 5},
                  {5, 6, 7},
                  {8, 9, 10},
                  {11, 12, 13}
                 };
```

Comment: What if I put all of this in the setup. Will it still be usable in the loop later?

Comment: @TalalC. you can do this as well, but there is a good chance initialization syntax I use will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your both answers my friend. Going your way

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix it as I need it in this format for clarity.

SergeyA's answer nails the problem -- you're trying to execute statements outside any function. If you don't want to use the array initialization syntax in his answer, then move your assignment statements inside a function. This is exactly the kind of thing that the `setup()` function is meant for, so putting your assignments in `setup()` is probably the right thing to do.

Comment: True, but it would incur run-time cost, while static initialization like mine is likely to be performed at compile-time.

Comment: Ok i tried but i an't use the array in the loop later. I don't want to use pointers too. Qorst nightmares of my life

Comment: @SergeyA I agree, and there's nothing wrong with your answer, but the OP expressed a desire to keep the same code arrangement.

Comment: @TalalC. You're working in C, so you're going to need to work past your pointer phobia.